# how do you substitute a repeating character both uppercase and lowercase with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, uppercase, lowercase, repeat

Say you have a word "Aabrakadaabra" and what you want to do is find the repeating characters and replace them with a single one. which in our case should return "Abrakadabra".

what i did was `re.sub(r"([a-zA-z])\1",r"\1","Aabrakadaabra")` which returns 'Aabrakadabra' and this regex cannot catch when there is an uppercase and a lowercase repeating. Im not sure if there is an easy, one liner way to do this but any help would be educative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE).

```
>>> re.sub(r"([a-zA-z])\1",r"\1","Aabrakadaabra", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'Abrakadabra'
```